# ZFS root pool free space

Tags: zfs, openindiana, zpool, illumos

I have an openindiana (oi_151a7) box where I used 30GB for the root partition during installation. This has become rpool1. I cannot figure out how to make the remaining 202 GB available. Looking for suggestions. My partition table as follows:

```
Current partition table (original):
Total disk cylinders available: 26469 + 2 (reserved cylinders)

Part      Tag    Flag     Cylinders         Size            Blocks
  0       root    wm       1 -  3912       29.97GB    (3912/0/0)   62846280
  1 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  2     backup    wu       0 -  3912       29.98GB    (3913/0/0)   62862345
  3   reserved    wm       1 - 26468      202.76GB    (26468/0/0) 425208420
  4 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  5 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  6 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  7 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  8       boot    wu       0 -     0        7.84MB    (1/0/0)         16065    
  9 unassigned    wm       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
```

Slice 3, was created by me, by hand, using the format utility. This is what I'm trying to turn into a usable file space.

When I run format, and select disk 0, I'm told c4t0d0s3 is part of the root pool:

```
root@oi01:~# format
Searching for disks...done

AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c4t0d0 <ATA-VB0250EAVER-HPG7 cyl 26469 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci103c,1609@11/disk@0,0
       1. c4t1d0 <ATA-INTEL SSDSC2CT06-300i-55.90GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci103c,1609@11/disk@1,0
       2. c4t2d0 <ATA-Maxtor 7L300S0-1G10-279.48GB>
      /pci@0,0/pci103c,1609@11/disk@2,0
Specify disk (enter its number): 0
selecting c4t0d0
[disk formatted]
/dev/dsk/c4t0d0s0 is part of active ZFS pool rpool1. Please see zpool(1M).
/dev/dsk/c4t0d0s3 is part of active ZFS pool rpool1. Please see zpool(1M).
[...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run format, and select disk 0, I'm told c4t0d0s3 is part of the root pool:

This would be because you've screwed up the slice - it is overlapping with `c4t0d0s0`. You would need a slice starting at cylinder 3913 to remove the overlap. Then you should be able to add it as a vdev to another pool (if this is what you are after).

If you just want to resize your root pool to use all available disk space, boot up a live CD, edit the root and backup slices accordingly to occupy the full disk and restart your system - your zpool should adapt automagically. If not, try toggling the "autoexpand" property of the rpool.

Further reading: http://www.distrans.org/wiki/unixsystems/opensolaris/growing_root_pool

Comment: Yep. that's it. Didn't spot that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: To undo the slice 3 cylinders, I had to set NOINUSE_CHECK=1;
export NOINUSE_CHECK, and then run format again.